# KendoUI Grid Custom Filter UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to implement a custom filter UI with a drop down box with some dummy data for now. I have followed the tutorial on the Kendo site (http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html) but it just isn't working for me :(.

Here is the function for the custom UI:

```
function relStatFilter(element)
  {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
      dataSource: ["Prospect", "Customer"],
      optionLabel: 'Select status'
    })
  }
```

And here is the column parameters it's being applied to:

```
...
{
            field: 'relStat', 
            filterable: 
            {
                ui: relStatFilter, 
                extra: false
            }, 
            title: '<abbr title=\'Relationship status\'>Rel stat</abbr>', 
            template: '#= ratio == 0 ? "<span class=text-info>Prospect</span>" : relStat == "Active" ? "<span class=text-success>Active</span>" : relStat == "At risk" ? "<span class=text-warning>At risk</span>" : "" #', 
        }, 
...
```

When I click the filter all I get is the standard "starts with" and the text input.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom filtering UI is available since 2012.3.1315. Make sure you are not using an older version. Using 2012.3.1315 the following code works as expected:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: [ { name: "Foo" }, { name: "Bar" }],
  filterable: {
    extra: false,
    operators: {
      string: {
        eq: "Is equal to",
        neq: "Is not equal to"
      }
    }
  },
  columns: [
    {
      field: "name",
      filterable: {
        ui: function(element) {
          element.kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: [ "Foo", "Bar"]
          });
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/uwiqow/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find where to download that version but I just took the code they use in their examples and it works perfectly.